# Parsing and Writing JSON using Ant

Tags: json, ant, rhino

Has anyone managed to parse and write JSON in a  task in Ant?

I need to parse a json file, modify it and then write it back on disk. I managed to parse it using the rhino engine from JDK 6 but i'm stuck because I don't know how to serialize it back to disk.

It seemes I need a JSON serializer, rhino does not apparently include one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of Rhino should have a JSON object: see this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505211) that was resolved as fixed in 2010, and the actual class is called [NativeJSON](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/rhino/src/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeJSON.java) and has a `stringify` method that should let you retrieve a JSON string.

Comment: I'm not sure what vertsion of Rhino is include with the JDK 6 (1.6.026) but it seems that nor JSON neither NativeJSON are available. Maybe if would be able to use BSF instead of the Rhino from JDK would work. Currently I cannot load the BSF script engine in ANT, I'm not sure what's the problem

Comment: Success! Your answer make me go back to using Rhino engine not Jdk engine. As soon I was able to load Apache BSF in Ant all the problems were gone. I was using the BSF 3.x instead of BSF 2.x, duh.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify is available with Rhino 1.7R3 onwards as part of the ECMAScript 5 work.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/New_in_Rhino_1.7R3